# Regex: How to make IsMatch to fail if a particular word matches in string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have to search a string for a few words eg, dog, cat, lion but I want regex to fail if lizard is found in the string even if it contains cat, dog or lion.

```
ismatch(pass) "dog|cat|lion" "This is not your average cat!"

ismatch (fail) [my regex statement] "This is not your average cat! It's a lizard."
```

[my regex statement] - here the regex statement is unknown, can you please help me to write this statement?

Word spaces and boundaries or lower/uppercase is not a concern. I run the string through

```
Replace(" ", "").Trim(" ").ToLower
```

before handover to Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using negative lookahead and negative look behind

```
(?<!lizard.*)(?:dog|cat|lion)(?!.*lizard)
```

If you use the Regex option ignore case you don't need to call tolower.  You can specify it by adding `(?i)` to the beginning of the regex string.

After comment by js_dudley here is a way to build the string up

```
var exclude=new string[] { "lizard","eagle"};
var include=new string[] {"dog","cat","lion"};
var regexString=string.Format(
                                "(?<!({0}).*)(?:{1})(?!.*({0}))",
                                string.Join("|",exclude),
                                string.Join("|",include)
                             );
var regex=new Regex(regexString);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I just wanted to know if I wanted to add additional words with lizard should I just separate them with a "|" after lizard eg. (?<!lizard|mouse.*)(?:dog|cat|lion)(?!.*lizard|mouse)  ???

Comment: @js_Dudley you probably want to use a bracket to make sure the if compares the correct words so `(?<!(lizard|mouse).*)(?:dog|cat|lion)(?!.*(lizard|mouse))`

Comment: This will not work in all flavors of regex ... many of them require lookaheads to be fixed-length, and the `.*` inside the lookahead group causes an error.  This similar, but slightly different, approach will work in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408 ... but I guess this works in vb.net

Answer (score 2):

If lookahead is not possible for some reason you can try this ugly trick: `(dog|cat|lion)([^l]|l[^i]|li[^z]|liz[^a]|liza[^r]|lizar[^d])*$`

Answer (score 0):

Is it not acceptable to simply use (syntax may not be perfect):

```
If nonLizardAnimalsRegex.IsMatch(yourString) And Not lizardRegex.IsMatch(yourString) Then
    ' String contains an animal but not "lizard"
End If
```